# Как заменить «КАПС» на «Нормальную нотацию»?

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения, строки

Нужно написать регулярное выражение, которое будет вычленять все слова, которые написаны «капсом» и переводить их в то же слово, написанное с заглавной буквы, а все остальные слова делать строчными.

Регулярка нужна для JavaScript, если это важно.

Выделить нужно слово — с этим нет проблем, а как сделать замену — ума не приложу.

Так не выходит:

```
''.replace(//, '$1' + '$2'.toLocaleLowerCase())
```

Comment: @higimo, Согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к решению либо завершению учебных заданий за учащихся. Пожалуйста, уточните, что вы сделали сами и что не получилось.

Comment: http://regex101.com/r/oA4uD7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://javascript.ru/string/replace

В большинстве языков программирования для регулярных выражений есть возможность callback-замен.
Вместо строки замены в `replace` передается функция, которая создает строку замены.

```js
var text = "THIS is CAPS и РУССКИЙ КАПС";
var re = /([А-ЯЁA-Z])([А-ЯЁA-Z]+)/ig;
var repl = function ( full, group1, group2 ) {
    return group1 + group2.toLowerCase();
};
var result = text.replace( re, repl );
document.body.innerHTML = result;
```

---

Для шаблона символов различных языков (если требуются отличные от ru и en) используйте вопрос:
[Как описать все символы некоторого языка в регулярном выражении? Есть ли готовые решения?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/440125/)