# Как описать все символы некоторого языка в регулярном выражении? Есть ли готовые решения?

Tags: регулярные-выражения, unicode

**Можно ли полагаться на то, что JVM «умным образом» разрешает диапазон "а-я" или "a-z" в регулярном выражении и добавляет в него все символы некоторого алфавита, который начинается на «а» и заканчивается на «я»?**

Ответ: нет, [диапазон читается буквально](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/440140/181472), и это [можно подтвердить экспериментом](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/440522/181472).

Символы Ё и ё не попадают в диапазон юникода, в котором лежат все кириллические символы русского языка. То же самое верно для существенной части других алфавитов: буквы в Unicode идут не подряд. Предлагаю отвлечься от особенностей кириллицы и подумать об абстрактном "a-z", где "a" и "z" — первая и последняя буква какого-то алфавита.

**Есть ли в Java готовое решение для того, чтобы описать все "родные" буквы в заданной локали?**

[Ответ: в Java нет, но есть в ответе к этому вопросу](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/440535/181472)

Нашел [про поддержку локалей](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/javase7locales-334809.html#util-text), но не вполне представляю, как это можно применить в регулярном выражении. Логично бы ожидать character class, какой-нибудь `\p{locale_Ru_Ru}`, но не нахожу.

Навеяно [этим ответом](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/432925/181472) к вопросу «Как определить не русский текст?»

Comment: Что мешает определить символьный класс [а-яА-яёЁ]?

Comment: @a_gura а в общем виде, если я ге знаю целевого языка?

Comment: В регулярных выражениях нет такой поддержки (скажем, почти нет), можно только использовать символьный класс для каждого. Я написал [такие для некоторых языков](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30798598/3832970), основываясь на данных из Википедии.

Comment: @stribizhev: О, здорово, полезную очень работу проделали. Может, здесь тоже опубликуете?

Comment: @NickVolynkin: Думаю, не стоит, так как вопрос тут несколько иной, и ответ (по-моему, правильный) уже дан. Регулярные выражения просто "тупо" берут данные из таблицы Юникода подряд между заданными границами диапазона и не знают ничего о языках, использующих данные символы.

Comment: Честно говоря с юникодом все довольно просто. Есть псевдокласс `\p{Cyrillic}`, добавив к нему класс пробелов и пунктуации получим желаемый результат.

Comment: @ReinRaus: это в Java есть? Я его почему-то не нашел в [документации](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)

Comment: Ох. Извините. Всегда думал, что раз Java позиционирует себя как язык поддерживающий Unicode из коробки, то в нем реализован этот функционал PCRE.

Comment: @ReinRaus: расскажите уж, где есть? в C#?

Comment: В шарпе есть, но он называется IsCyrillic, а так гарантированно в php и естественно в perl.

Comment: @stribizhev: я все-таки перевел и немного адаптировал ваш ответ, т.к. он вполне отвечает на мой второй вопрос. См. ссылку в вопросе и http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/440535/181472

Comment: @NickVolynkin: Мой ответ, честно говоря, неполный, я собирался (и, наверное, так и сделаю как-нибудь на досуге) пополнить список. Так как я специалист явно не по всем языкам даже Европы, некоторых тонкостей, скорее всего, не учёл.

Comment: @stribizhev: пингуйте, как сделаете. Если сам дополню — сообщу тоже.

Comment: @NickVolynkin: кстати, а что если сделать на гитхабе, например, класс со строковыми константами и обновлять его?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Регулярки просто включают диапазон между порядковыми значениями символов.

[Полный кириллический диапазон](http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U0400.pdf) безусловно включает `Ёё` и многое другое.  Так что, чтобы собрать базовую кириллицу, достаточно задать диапазон вида `[\x400-\x4ff]` (не уверен что точный синтаксис для этого формата в Java).

Comment: у меня речь о диапазоне a-z или а-я. Я знаю, что в него входит в юникоде, но не вполне уверен, что то же самое входит в регулярках. О том и вопрос. Диапазон `[\x400-\x4ff]`, конечно, включает Ёё, но там есть и много лишнего. Об этом второй вопрос — нет ли готового решения. Похоже, что нет.

Comment: @NickVolynkin если у вас речь о `a-z` как об "алфавите" то думаю в случае англ. языка здесь речь просто об удобном совпадении, остальное ручками, как выше уже написали. Да, я в нём, надеюсь знаете в хорошем смысле :)

Comment: Нуууу. Это не является диапазоном ни для русского, ни для украинского, ни для белорусского, ни для болгарского, ни для какого-то другого _определённого_ языка — чем же это тогда является?

Answer (score 13):

## Готовые выражения для всех символов в заданной локали

Все ответы, где отдельно не указан источник, основаны на [Useful ASCII Ranges](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-interesting-character-classes.html#languages). Этот ответ основан на [ответе stribizhev на EN.SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30798598/2790048).

Кроме первых двух, отсортировано по алфавиту.

#### Русский алфавит ([wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Russian_alphabet))

```
[а-яА-ЯёЁ]
```

#### Вся латиница плюс акцентированные символы

```
(?![×÷])[A-Za-zÀ-ÿ]
```

#### Белорусский алфавит ([wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Belarusian_alphabet))

```
[ёа-зй-шы-яЁА-ЗЙ-ШЫІіЎў]
```

#### Болгарский алфавит (является подмножеством русского) ([wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bulgarian_alphabet))

```
[а-ъьюяА-ЪЬЮЯ]
```

#### Греческий и коптский алфавиты вместе: ([wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greek_alphabet))

```
[\u0370-\u03FF\u1F00-\u1FFF]
```

#### Испанский алфавит

```
[a-zA-ZáéíñóúüÁÉÍÑÓÚÜ]
```

#### Итальянский алфавит

[a-zA-ZàèéìíîòóùúÀÈÉÌÍÎÒÓÙÚ]

#### Немецкий алфавит

```
[a-zA-ZäöüßÄÖÜẞ]
```

#### Норвежский алфавит ([wikipedia](http://www.fiskeklubben.org/charcters/digitized.html))

```
[a-zA-ZæøåÆØÅ]
```

#### Польский алфавит

```
[a-pr-uwy-zA-PR-UWY-ZąćęłńóśźżĄĆĘŁŃÓŚŹŻ]
```

В польском языке нет заглавных букв `Q`, `V` and `X`. Если нужен **польский + латиница:**

```
[a-zA-ZąćęłńóśźżĄĆĘŁŃÓŚŹŻ]
```

#### Румынский алфавит ([wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Romanian_alphabet))

```
[a-zA-ZĂÂÎȘȚăâîșț]
```

#### Сербский алфавит (кириллица) ([wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serbian_Cyrillic_alphabet))

```
[А-ИК-ШЂЈ-ЋЏа-ик-шђј-ћџ]
```

#### Украинский ([wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ukrainian_alphabet))

[Апостроф — тоже буква](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ukrainian_alphabet#Alphabet).

```
[а-щА-ЩЬьЮюЯяЇїІіЄєҐґ']
```

#### Французский алфавит

```
[a-zA-ZàâäôéèëêïîçùûüÿæœÀÂÄÔÉÈËÊÏÎŸÇÙÛÜÆŒ]
```

#### Шведский алфавит ([wikipedia](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1669503/3832970))

```
[a-zA-ZäöåÄÖÅ]
```

Comment: С польским и, думаю, другими языками, основанными на части латинницы, есть такая проблема, что многие заимствованные слова также имеют оригинальное написание. "Такси" по-польски "taxi", хотя в алфавите отсутствуте буква "x". А в украинским, вообще, апостроф может быть буквой (см. комментарий @Vlad к моему ответу).

Comment: Вот [пруф](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ukrainian_alphabet#Alphabet), чтобы не оставаться голословным: _The alphabet comprises thirty-three letters, representing thirty-eight phonemes (meaningful units of sound), and an additional sign—the apostrophe._

Comment: А английский, несмотря на формальное отсутствие в алфавите акцентов, вполне себе использует формы café, naïveté и Übermensch.

Comment: По немецкому, заглавная ß практически не используется, вместо неё пишут двойное S. В реальности `upcase("Spaß")` должно выдавать `"SPASS"`.

Comment: @VladD: для английского можно использовать расширенную латиницу, второе выражение.

Answer (score 2):

Самому стало интересно как все это будет выглядеть в диапазонах символов:

```java
int c = Character.MIN_VALUE;
int low = -1;
Pattern pat = Pattern.compile( "^[а-яА-Я]$" );
while ( c <= (int) Character.MAX_VALUE ) {
    if ( pat.matcher( String.valueOf( (char) c ) ).matches() ) {
        if ( low == -1 ) low = c;
    } else {
        if ( low > -1 ) {
            System.out.println( Integer.toHexString( low ) + " - " + Integer.toHexString(c-1) );
            low = -1;
        }
    }
    c++;
}
```

Для данной регулярки это

```
410 - 44f
```

Так что решается все очень просто: как и написал @Petr Abdulin

Comment: Я тут узнал про комбинированные символы и нормализацию Юникода, и понял, что для многих языков просто диапазона недостаточно. Нужно убедиться, что реализация регулярок «понимает», что `a`+ умлаут — это тоже `ä`. Или вот в польском: `o` нет, а `ó` есть.

Comment: Наверное всё это означает, что не нужно пытаться регулярками определять языковую принадлежность текста. ))

Comment: А в чём разница между проверкой регулярными выражениями и написанием кучи условий сравнения нативным кодом ?

Comment: Я имел в виду не столько метод, сколько путь решения. Т.е. не по четкому набору символов (который можно проверять хоть регулярками, хоть кучей условий), а по какой-то другой эвристике. Может, по словарям искать совпадения.

Comment: Иначе «Варкалось. Хливкие шорьки пыряли по наве.» распознается как русский текст, что спорно. )

Comment: Тут нужен искусственный интеллект тогда :) Ну или хотя бы словарь :)