# Регулярное выражение для поиска слов на украинском языке

Tags: c#, регулярные-выражения

Есть следующее регулярное выражение:

```
Regex regex = new Regex("^[А-Яа-я]+$");
```

Он работает правильно, но не "понимает" украинский язык. Т.е. он "скушает" "фывапролдж", а это нет - "іилрилії".

Как сделать так, чтобы эта регулярка "понимала" украинский язык?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Вам необходимо дополнить символьный класс символами `ёЁЇїІіЄєҐґ`:

```
"^[А-Яа-яёЁЇїІіЄєҐґ]+$"
```

Это регулярное выражение для букв украинского языка (информацию я брал из [Википедии](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ukrainian_alphabet)):

```
[а-щА-ЩЬьЮюЯяЇїІіЄєҐґ]
```

Возможно, надо добавить сюда `'` (см. [комментарий Влада](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30798522/regular-expression-not-working-for-at-least-one-european-character/30798598#comment51683029_30798598)).

По поводу `ёЁ`: [эти буквы в таблице Юникода](http://jrgraphix.net/r/Unicode/0400-04FF) находятся вне диапазона остальный букв, поэтому её надо указывать отдельно. Диапазон заглавных букв русского языка выглядит как `U+0410 - U+042F`, диапазон строчных - `U+0430 - U+044F`. `Ё` имеет код `U+0401`, а `ё` — `U+0451`.

И ещё: в .NET можно указать все кириллические символы с помощью `\p{IsCyrillic}` (U+0400 - U+04FF) и, для полноты, `\p{IsCyrillicSupplement}` (U+0500 - 052F), и тогда выражение примет форму

```
@"^[\p{IsCyrillic}\p{IsCyrillicSupplement}]+$"
```

Ну, или `@"^['\p{IsCyrillic}\p{IsCyrillicSupplement}]+$"`.

Comment: Возможно, имеет смысл добавить насчёт `IsCyrillic` в [этот ответ](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/440535/). (Хотя там и про Java.)

Comment: Простите, заметил одну неточность, предоставленное вами регулярное выражение для украинского языка включает в себя букву русского алфавита: "ы".

Comment: @EvgeniyMiroshnichenko [`[а-щА-ЩЬьЮюЯяЇїІіЄєҐґ]`](https://regex101.com/r/oPNSN4/1) не находит `ы`. `^[А-Яа-яёЁЇїІіЄєҐґ]+$` - это регулярное выражение из вопроса, в которой добавлены украинские буквы, так как вопрос был сделать так, "чтобы эта регулярка (`^[А-Яа-я]+$`) "понимала" украинский язык".

Answer (score 6):

Я бы рекомендовал такое выражене:

```
Regex regex = new Regex("^[\u0400-\u052F\u2DE0-\u2DFF\uA640-\uA69F']+$");
```

Это понимает все [кириллические буквы в Юникоде](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0_%D0%B2_%D0%AE%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5), например такие буквы:

- РусскийЫыЁёЭэЪъ
- УкраїнськаІіЇїЄє'
- БеларускаяЎў
- СрпскиЂђЉљЊњЋћЏџ
- СлавянскиеБуквыѰѱѬѭѨѩ

и так далее.

Если *только* хочешь украинские и русские буквы, вот это подходит:

```
new Regex("^[А-Яа-яЁёЇїІіЄєҐґ']+$");
```