# Как учитывать регистр буквы и не учитывать при помощью скрипта в переводчике

Tags: javascript, jquery, регулярные-выражения

Ест такой скрипт который меняет одно текст на другую

```js
(function() {
  if (!$('.translate').size()) return;
  var words = [
    ['Форум', 'Forum'],
    ['Форума', 'Forumun'],
    ['форум', 'forum'],
    ['форума', 'forumun'],
    ['Темы', 'Mövzular'],
    ['Тема', 'Mövzu'],
    ['темы', 'mövzular'],
    ['тема', 'mövzu']


  ];
  $('.translate').each(function() {
    var html = this.innerHTML;
    for (i = 0, j = words.length; i < j; i++) {
      html = html.replace(new RegExp(words[i][0], 'gi'), words[i][1]);
    }
    this.innerHTML = html;
  });
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="translate">
  <div>Форум</div>
  <div>Форума</div>
  <div>форум</div>
  <div>форума</div>
  <div>Темы</div>
  <div>Тема</div>
  <div>темы</div>
  <div>тема</div>


</div>
```

Но как видно что написанный текст с маленькими буквами не учитывается,
порядок должен такой. 
Слово **Форум** должен заменятся на **Forum** 
Слово **Форума** должен заменятся на **Forumun** 
Слово **Форум** должен заменятся на **forum** 
Слово **форума** должен заменятся на **forumun**
Слово **Темы** должен заменятся на **Mövzular** 
Слово **Тема** должен заменятся на **Mövzu**

еще проблема в том что если ест таких слово 
**пожарное** , **по рейтингу** 
при смене текста должен получится 
**Yanğın söndürən** , **ilə reyting**
а скрипт меняет как попало,
допустим вот так

```js
(function() {
  if (!$('.translate').size()) return;
  var words = [
    ['пожарное', 'yanğın söndürən'],
    ['по', 'ilə'],
    ['рейтингу', 'reytinqlə'],

  ];
  $('.translate').each(function() {
    var html = this.innerHTML;
    for (i = 0, j = words.length; i < j; i++) {
      html = html.replace(new RegExp(words[i][0], 'gi'), words[i][1]);
    }
    this.innerHTML = html;
  });
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="eTitile eMessage eBlock translate">
  <div>пожарное</div>
  <div>по</div>
  <div>рейтингу</div>
  <div>поезд</div>
</div>
```

как нашел первую слово сменил, а слово пожарное 
сменился по частями ***ilə***жарное
ну как надо сделать чтоб.
если меняем слово **форум** менялся на **forum**
а если в этом же строке есть еще похоже слово **форум по авто**
слово форум отделено не менялся, а менялся как указываем вот так.
**Форум** на **Forum**
**Форум по авто** на **avtomobil forumu**
**по** на **ilə**

Comment: Для первого случая смените `'gi'` на `'g'`. Для второго случая могу порекомендовать только длинные слова ставить первыми в массиве, иначе нужно менять подход к замене слов.

Comment: @Visman Спасибо за помощь! про порядок длинных текстов в начале вставил, получилось. а это помогает **'gi'** на **'g'** запрет смене не заглавными буквами и с заглавными буквами **А,а** но есть еще проблема, условия **else** надо так сделать чтоб, если в скрипте указано слово **Привет Петя**=**Salam Petya** и **Привет**=**Salam**, менялся только то слово,   если в скрипте будет такое смена **и**=**və** скрипт меняет вот так **Пр_və_вет**, как избежать с таких случай? условия _else_ если нашел **и** тогда **və** если **привет** тогда оставит **привет** а не так  **Пр_və_вет**

Answer (score 1):

Можно сократить количество шаблонов вдвое, если использовать функцию обратного вызова при замене:

```js
var words = [
    ['форум', 'forum'],
    ['форума', 'forumun'],
    ['темы', 'mövzular'],
    ['тема', 'mövzu']
];


var html = "Форум форум подфорум Форума форума темы Темы подтема тема Тема";

for (i = 0, j = words.length; i < j; i++) {
  var re = new RegExp( "([^а-яё]|^)(" + words[i][0] + ")(?=[^а-яё]|$)", 'gi');
  var repl = words[i][1];
  html = html.replace( re, function( full, m1, m2 ) {
    if ( m2.charAt(0).toUpperCase() == m2.charAt(0) ) {
        return m1 + repl.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + repl.slice(1);
    } else {
        return m1 + repl;
    }
  } );
};
console.log( html );
```

Результат:

```
Forum forum подфорум Forumun forumun mövzular Mövzular подтема mövzu Mövzu
```

Регулярное выражение сделано с учетом, что исходный язык - русский. Для других языков можно составить регулярное выражение используя вопрос:
[Как описать все символы некоторого языка в регулярном выражении? Есть ли готовые решения?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/440125/)

---

**Бонус**
Если изначально делать страницу на английском языке, то код будет значительно проще:

```js
var words = [
  ['forum', 'forum'],
  ['forums', 'forumun'],
  ['thread', 'mövzular'],
  ['threads', 'mövzu']
];


var html = "Forum forum subforum Forums forums Thread thread subthread Threads threads";

for (i = 0, j = words.length; i < j; i++) {
  var re = new RegExp( "\\b" + words[i][0] + "\\b", 'gi');
  var repl = words[i][1];
  html = html.replace( re, function( full ) {
    if ( full.charAt(0).toUpperCase() == full.charAt(0) ) {
      return repl.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + repl.slice(1);
    } else {
      return repl;
    }
  } );
};
console.log( html );
```

Результат:

```
Forum forum subforum Forumun forumun Mövzular mövzular subthread Mövzu mövzu
```

Comment: у меня страницы на русском языке, меня подходит первый вариант, но есть маленькие проблемы, это строка не подходит  `var html = "Форум форум";` из за того что, если на странице есть 10000 и боле слов, их надо написать в эту строку, и в массив перевода, я эту строку не вставил в скрипт, работает отлично, ищет и меняет то что указано, но заглавные буквы не определяет, если указано **Форум и форум** а мне надо чтоб форум, скрипт как увидеть первую Форум , и на выдаче дает Forum, есть какой не будь другой вариант? [вот скрипт](http://avtousta.ucoz.com/js/translate_az.js)

Comment: уже эту тоже поправил **gi** менял на **g** теперь переводит БОЛЬШИМИ с большими маленькими с маленькими, и добавил такую строку `а-яА-ЯёЁ` место этого   `а-яё`

Comment: О_О `из за того что, если на странице есть 10000 и боле слов, их надо написать в эту строку` . Это пример О_о Способ доставки текста в этот код на Ваш вкус.