# пробелы в названиях файлов

Tags: регулярные-выражения, shell, sed

есть файлы с пробелами в названиях
и есть такая команда:

```
p=$(for f in [а-Я]*.txt; do n=$(sed '$a\' $f | wc -l); echo -n "| tee >(head -n $n > new/$f) | tail -n $((s-n)) "; done)
```

но она не хочет работать из за пробелов в названиях файлов.
или я маску неправильно подобрал?

Как решить проблему?

Comment: `[а-Я]`, кстати, не выглядит правильным паттерном: русские буквы идут [не подряд](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/440125/10105).

Comment: Правильно я понимаю, что нужно выбрать только txt-файлы с кириллическими именами?

Comment: да, txt файлы с кириллическими доменами

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> не хочет работать из за пробелов в названиях файлов

заключите переменную, содержащую имя файла, в двойные кавычки:

```
... "$f" ...
```

---

> или я маску неправильно подобрал?

так проверьте, какие файлы подпадают под маску:

```
$ ls маска
```

Comment: когда проверяю это паттерн [а-я]* через $ ls , то машина отображает нужные мне файлы, но когда использую его в деле, то возникает проблема с пробелами, машина воспринимает пробел как окончание названия файла . "$f" кавычки не помогли

Comment: Допустим есть файл "текстовый файл.txt" , применяю команду описанную в топике и получаю: "sed: невозможно прочитать текстовый: No such file or directory
sed: невозможно прочитать файл.txt: No such file or directory"

Comment: попробуйте выяснить, в чём причина, методом упрощения выражения. кстати, у вас там ещё раз встречается `$f`. там просто `"$f"` не пойдёт, т.к. строка уже находится в кавычках.

Comment: в некоторых случаях в подобной ситуации бывает проще переименовать файлы, чем «заниматься сексом» с их извращёнными именами.

Comment: думаю можно заменить пробелы в названиях символами подчеркивания. Вы случайно не знаете как это сделать массово?

Comment: `prename 's/ /_/g' *`