# Шаблон для валидации кириллических символов в JAVA

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения

Необходимо составить регулярное выражение для проверки наличия кириллических символов в строке. Как такое можно реализовать?

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/440125/10105

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Не совсем ясен вопрос проверка вхождения,только ли из символов кириллицы (к слову кириллица понятие [растяжимое](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0_%D0%B2_%D0%AE%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5)) состоит строка или нечто другое.Но по сути вопроса выражение типа  `[а-яА-Я]+` вернет Вам `true` при наличии в строке хотя бы одного включения перечисленных символов.

Ну и от себя дополню ответ методом проверки наличия символов кириллицы в строке:

```
public boolean isCyrillic(String s) {
    boolean result = false;
    for (char a : s.toCharArray()) {
        if (Character.UnicodeBlock.of(a) == Character.UnicodeBlock.CYRILLIC) {
            result = !result;
            break;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

**UPD**:
к ответу @Aleksei Chibisov
Да не вернет. Собственно к этому и ремарка "кириллица понятие растяжимое" - самих символов которые относятся к данной группе масса. К кириллическим алфавитам относятся: Белорусский,Болгарский,Сербский,Македонский,Русский,Украинский ...и такие символы как є i w ... и куча других...Как по мне стоит в данном случае использовать именно UnicodeBlock - там присутствуют расширения A и B c версии 1.7
И реакция метода представленного выше на символ 'ё' или 'є' - будет `true`

Answer (score 6):

Для работы с регулярными выражениями в Java существуют классы Pattern и Matcher:

```
 String regex = "[а-яёА-ЯЁ]+";
 String str = "Работа не walk - работа work";

 Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
 Matcher m = pattern.matcher(str);
 if (m.find()){
    //делаем что-то
 }
```

К предыдущему ответу добавлю что [а-яА-Я]+ не включает символы ё и Ё

Comment: Да вы правы, мне нужно было это просто отметить в комментарии в вашему ответу.[а-яёА-ЯЁ] это лишь полный набор символов русского алфавита, а не всей кириллицы в целом