# Проверить принадлежность текста культуре

Tags: c#

Есть в C# готовые методы проверки по типу

```
var culture = new CultureInfo("ru");
var text = "hello world";
var isRu = text.Of(culture); //false
```

Comment: Что значит принадлежность текста культуре?

Comment: Алфавитов не так уж много: латиница, кириллица, ...

Comment: Да, именно алфавитные символы проверить

Comment: Сомневаюсь, что есть готовые методы в стандартной библиотеке. Но вы можете написать нужные методы самостоятельно.

Comment: Помнится, получил похожее задание я пару лет назад как тестовое на собеседовании :) Тут нет простого способа самому реализовывать распознаватель культуры, ибо символы могут быть одинаковыми, но там в основном все зависит от порядка их следования и других факторов. Решение было у меня простое - использовал `Google Language API`

Comment: [Как описать все символы некоторого языка в регулярном выражении? Есть ли готовые решения?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/440125/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b2%d1%81%d0%b5-%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8b-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%ba%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d1%8f%d0%b7%d1%8b%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%b2-%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b3%d1%83%d0%bb%d1%8f%d1%80%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bc-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%95%d1%81%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b3%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b5)

Answer (score 2):

Если ваша задача проверить принадлежность символов строки к определенному алфавиту (без учета валидности слов в каком-то языке), то давайте напишем такой простой класс с методами-расширения:

```
public static class CultureHelper
{
    static readonly string whitespaceChars = @" .,-()!?";
    static readonly string cyrillicChars = "абвгдеёжзийклмнопрстуфхцчшщъыьэюяАБВГДЕЁЖЗИЙКЛМНОПРСТУФХЦЧШЩЪЫЬЭЮЯ";

    public static bool IsCyrillicText(this string s)
    {
        return s.All(c => cyrillicChars.Contains(c) || whitespaceChars.Contains(c));
    }
}
```

Изпользование:

```
Console.WriteLine("Привет, мир!".IsCyrillicText());
Console.WriteLine("Hello, world!".IsCyrillicText());
Console.WriteLine("Привет, John!".IsCyrillicText());
```

Вывод:

```
True
False
False
```

Comment: Спасибо за пример реализации, но у меня нет проблем с написанием подобного. Просто время затратно искать все символы всех алфавитов

Comment: @DenisJNewb - я вот тоже помучался с поиском всех символов алфавитов (можете заценить ревизии моего ответа (фэйспалм)), в итоге нашёл нужную комбинацию категорий и блоков регулярок.

Answer (score 2):

В платформе .NET очень мощные регулярные выражения.

Для поставленной задачи можно применить [общие категории Юникода](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/20bw873z(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_11) и [именованные блоки](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/20bw873z(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_12).

Сдалем метод расширения, как в ответе Андрея. Только вместо вручную заданных диапазонов символов возьмём готовые.

```
public static class CultureHelper
{
    public static bool IsCyrillicText(this string s)
    {
        return s.Where(c => Regex.IsMatch(c.ToString(), @"\p{L}"))
            .All(c => Regex.IsMatch(c.ToString(), @"\p{IsCyrillic}"));
    }
}

Console.WriteLine("Привет, мир!".IsCyrillicText()); // True
Console.WriteLine("Hello, world!".IsCyrillicText()); // False
Console.WriteLine("Привет, John!".IsCyrillicText()); // False
```

Метод сперва отфильтровывает из текста только буквы, потом проверяет их на принаделжность к нужной группе. Это гарантирует корректную работу с любыми символами Юникода.