# Как убрать из строки лишние символы при помощи RegEx?

Tags: c#, регулярные-выражения

Как убрать из строки любые символы, кроме знаков пунктуации и символов русского & английского алфавита?

Под знаками пунктуации я имел в виду эти:

```
( !@#$%^&*()_+=-'\:|/`~.,{} )
```

Делаю TCP чат и обнаружил ужасный недочет связанный с тем, что возможно отправить символы, ломающие графическую оболочку чата. Целая куча повторяющихся символов, вылезающих за грань контролов.

Comment: и даже цифры убрать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Большинство ваших знаков пунктуации является спецсимволами, их надо экранировать, проще всего это сделать функцией Regex.Escape, не обязательно делать это прям в коде, можно подготовить регулярку в linqpad, и затем использовать готовую уже в коде.

```
var escaped = Regex.Escape(@"( !@#$%^&*()_+=-'\:|/`~.,{})");
```

В результате получите строку *'(\ !@#\$%\^&*()_+=-'\:\|/`~.,{})'*
но она вам не подойдёт, надо ещё экранировать символ диапозона `-`, и можно пробел `\` заменить на пробельный символ `\s`, в результате получим:

```
var escapedChars = @"\(\s!@\#\$%\^&\*\(\)_\+=\-'\\:\|/`~\.,\{}\)";
```

Замену символов можно реализовать уже так:

```
private static readonly Regex _invalidCharactersRegex = new Regex(@"[^a-zа-я\(\s!@\#\$%\^&\*\(\)_\+=\-'\\:\|/`~\.,\{}\)]+", 
    RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
public string ReplaceInvalidCharacters(string str) => 
   _invalidCharactersRegex.Replace(str, "");
```

Пример использования:

```
void Main()
{
    Console.WriteLine(ReplaceInvalidCharacters("Ваша строка"));
}
```

Если числа вам тоже нужны, то можно заменить в регулярке `a-zа-я` на `\w`, и убрать опцию `RegexOptions.IgnoreCase`:

```
private static readonly Regex _invalidCharactersRegex = new Regex(@"[^\w\(\s!@\#\$%\^&\*\(\)_\+=\-'\\:\|/`~\.,\{}\)]+");
```

Comment: [ёЁ и другие символы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/440125/)